# Heisenberg uncertainty and Lorentz contraction

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, lorentz-symmetry

Consider a particle in a frame moving with speed $v$ relative to the lab frame. By Lorentz contraction, the width of the wavefunction will be smaller in the lab frame, resulting in smaller $\Delta x$. If $v$ is high enough, then the uncertainty principle $\Delta x \Delta p \ge \hbar/2$ will be violated in the lab frame.

What's wrong here? Does $\Delta p$ increase somehow? This seems unlikely, since simply translating momentum distribution by a constant should not alter the standard deviation.

Comment: $p=\gamma m v$. That's very basic special relativity. If you make all the momenta bigger, you make the standard deviation bigger. Try it: find the standard deviation of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 vs. 2, 4, 6, 8, 10.

Comment: But we are adding a constant value to p, not multiplying every value by a constant. 1,2,3,4,5 vs 2,3,4,5,6 have the same standard deviation! Let's say that in the particle's co-moving frame the momentum is distributed symmetrically around p=0. The values of momentum in the lab frame should be distributed also symmetrically but around $p=\gamma mv$, where v is the relative speed of the frames. So I don't understand your reasoning why $\Delta p$ should  increase.

Comment: No. When you increase v you also increase $\gamma$, and that's a multiplicative change to p.

Comment: +1: Interesting question! I presume that a satisfactory answer cannot come from simple QM and I am not exactly clear on how this question gets translated into QFT (and back).

Comment: Wave function in QFT is invariant under such a transformation, which means there shouldn't be a problem like that. In non relativistic QM theory you will get a wrong answer.

Comment: seeing that there is no accepted answer has anyone successfully managed to conduct the OP's thought experiment in QFT or some version of RQM?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to apply relativity (Lorentz contraction) to a result from nonrelativistic quantum mechanics (Heisenberg uncertainty), so of course you get a contradiction.

In nonrelativistic quantum mechanics, the effect of a boost is given by the Galilean transformation
$$\psi(x) \to \exp((im/\hbar) (vx + v^2t/2))\, \psi(x-vt)$$
as explained in more detail [here](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aapt/journal/ajp/44/11/10.1119/1.10206). You can verify by explicit calculation that this shifts position eigenvalues as
$$x \to x-vt$$
and shifts momentum eigenvalues by
$$p \to p-mv$$
as expected classically. Since both position and momentum are simply shifted, $\Delta x \Delta p$ stays the same, and the uncertainty principle is preserved.

Comment: But the question is about what happens in relativistic theory, you did not address that.

Comment: I agree that this is how the question of boost should be handled in proper QM. However, I am a bit puzzled as to how to translate this question into QFT and back.

Answer (score 0):

With apologies for the many typos (and worse) in the first version of this answer:

Write the wave function as $f(x)$ in the comoving frame.  Then in the lab frame, the wave function is $g(x)=\sqrt{a}f(ax)$ where $a$ is some positive constant.

Write $\hat{f}(x)$ for the Fourier transform of $f$. Then $\hat{g}(x)=\hat{f}(x/a)/\sqrt{a}$.

The change in frame changes the variance of position from $\int x^2 |f(x)|^2$ to $\int x^2 |g(x)|^2$, which means the variance is multiplied by $1/a^2$.  (Check this by substituting $u=a x$ in the second integral.)

The change in frame changes the variance of momentum from $\int x^2|\hat{f}(x)|^2$ to $\int x^2 |\hat{g}(x)|^2$, which means the variance is multiplied by $a^2$. (Check this by substituting $u=x/a$ in the second integral.)

The product of the variances is therefore unchanged.

While I hope the above is enlightening, it's really unnecessary. The key is that $f$ is some arbitrary wave function and $g$ is some other wave function. Some argument must have convinced you that $f$ satisfies the uncertainty principle in the first place.  Whatever that argument is, it applies equally well to $g$.

Comment: Why is $/Delta x$ larger in the lab frame? Shouldn't it be smaller due to Lorentz contraction? The uncertainty relation should be preserved in the lab frame, i.e. $/Delta x' /Delta p' = /Delta x /Delta p /ge 1/2$.

Comment: This is very strange. The momentum distribution after a boost should be a shifted version of the original momentum distribution. Under your reasoning, a boost would change the momentum of a plane wave by a multiplicative factor, rather than simply adding a constant to it.

Comment: @knzhou:  I understand your concern --- but do you see a problem with the math?

Comment: The math looks right, but I'm not convinced that this is the right relationship between the lab and boosted wavefunctions. The Schrodinger equation is not relativistic.

Comment: @knzhou:  I am comparing the frames of two observers, in the same place at the same time, in relative motion with respect to each other --- and I am assuming a wave function that does not vary with time.   Does that help?  I do agree that if the wave function is changing over time, things are probably more complicated.

Comment: It's not that I'm worried about how you're applying special relativity; I think special relativity can't be applied at all. The theory of nonrelativistic quantum mechanics is, well, nonrelativistic. It allows wavefunctions to go faster than the speed of light. It has the energy-momentum relationship $E = p^2/2m$ instead of $E = mc^2$. So I don't see how something like the Lorentz boost can be used.

Comment: @knzhou:  All I'm saying is that we have one observer who assigns the coordinate $ax$ to the point where the other observer assigns the coordinate $x$, where $a$ is a Lorentz factor.  That means that if the observers agree on the value of the wave function at each point, and one says that function is $f(x)$, the other must say it's (up to a scale factor) $f(ax)$ --- and then the scale factor has to be $\sqrt{a}$ to keep the square of the integral equal to $1$.  SR has almost nothing to do with it--- all that matters is that one observer multiplies the other's coordinates by a fixed factor.

Comment: @knzhou --- just to re-emphasize (though I realize it's probably unnecessary):  The various problems with SR vs nonrelativistic QM seem to me to be red herrings, because we're not really invoking anything about SR here --- just two observers, one of whom has decided to measure distance in inches and the other in meters  --- and those observers **will** disagree about the values of $\Delta x$ and $\Delta p$ (though not about their product).

Comment: @WillO Your last comment is really important I guess. The procedure laid out in your answer does exactly what you said--it makes a change of units. However, how things will be seen in a frame in relative motion wrt the lab frame will not be captured by this. Because, the relevant transformation is not $x\to ax$ but rather $x\to ax+bt$. So, we will inevitably have to include the dependence on time because there is no shared instant of time by the two observers. And then, things will get very ugly IMO because Schrodinger equation is not Lorentz invariant.